# Disable help when mouse hovers on modeline

Tags: emacs

When the mouse hovers on the modeline, a few lines of help appear (depending on the context).

How do I disable this help? I would like to do so because (at least for Emacs 23 on OS X Lion), the help does not go away if I switch to another program without moving the mouse.

Comment: You might like to try a newer version of Emacs, and if the problem is still present in the latest release, use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean a tooltip by "a few lines of help", you can let help strings be displayed in the echo area rather than a pop-up window:

```lisp
(tooltip-mode nil)                      ; one-line help text in the echo area
```

or

```lisp
(setq tooltip-use-echo-area t)          ; multi-line help text in the echo area
```

In case that you want Emacs not to display help strings at all, you can set the `show-help-function` variable to `nil`:

```lisp
(tooltip-mode nil)
(setq show-help-function nil)
```

---

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>`tooltip-mode`</kbd>

> When Tooltip mode is disabled, Emacs displays one line of the help text in the echo area, and does not make a pop-up window.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>`tooltip-use-echo-area`</kbd>

> Use the echo area instead of tooltip frames for help and GUD tooltips. To display multi-line help text in the echo area, set this to t and enable `tooltip-mode`.

[32.19.4 Properties with Special Meanings, GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html#index-inhibit_002dpoint_002dmotion_002dhooks-2977)

> Variable: `show-help-function`
>
> If this variable is non-nil, it specifies a function called to display help strings. These may be `help-echo` properties, menu help strings, or tool bar help strings. The specified function is called with one argument, the help string to display. Tooltip mode provides an example.

Comment: So "tooltip" is what these are called. Thanks. But surely there must be a way to turn off both kinds of tooltips, no?

Comment: @Calaf `(setq show-help-function nil)` although it will deactivate tooltips for tool bar buttons, menu items and so forth as well as the mode line. AFAIK, there is no easy way to inhibit Emacs from diplaying help strings only for the mode line.